# Should we use integer strictly when we layout controls in iOS? Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I need to draw a line on the screen. The designer tell me to set the height of line to 2.5 pt. I'm wondering if it's acceptable to use decimal here.

I know it will be better if we use integer as the size or position of a `UIView`. But I can't tell why. I didn't find any convincing document about it.
So could anyone explain it or find something for me?

The only problem I know is `UILabel` with decimal size will be blurry. Is there any other problem like performance problem would happen?

Comment: Retina screens will recognize half points. It's safe to use floats of course since frames are CGRects. The device will handle estimating the values for the points onto the display. It is convention, though, to stick to half or whole points in most cases. Anything finer than that is extremely nit picky and makes the layout math harder to maintain.

Comment: @markedwardmurray iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 could handle the 2.5 points properly I think. But how about iPhone 6 Plus? I mean it's not a whole pixel and it needs more calculation. And I think it's kind of unexpectable thing we should avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your case it's just about half point which in my opinion should be ok. I often find that in storyboards my frames get moved 0.5 point up or down when I have lot of UI elements and sometimes constraints just get confused.

Additionally: the easiest scenario when your frame could be positioned at "some 0.5 point" is if you use a constraint to centre your view in it's superview. In this case the default x or y frame position could easily end up being "some 0.5 point". So it can happen often times and could be done by Xcode itself, so that's why I think your view will be just fine.

As stated previous in comments those points are CGFloat. What we have now is 1x, 2x and 3x resolutions. So there will always be the need for some calculations for at least one of the devices.

You may also look at this [Screen resolutions guide](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) to see all the time when up sampling and downsampling occurs.